# How do I create a local menu action to node/add/page?

Tags: 8, navigation

Here is the code in mymodule.links.action.yml to add a local action in a custom page (generated by the Views module).

```
amidori_utils.add_content:
  route_name: 'node.add_page'
  title: 'Add Content'
  appears_on:
    - view.admin_blogs.page_1
```

The above page will create a local action menu, which will take you to node/add page which will again list links to various content that you can create.

What I want is to create a link to node/add/blog as a local action. How can I do it?

After watching to the content of the node.routing.yml file, I understand I need to use node.add as route, but I can't figure out how to pass *blog* as parameter to the end of the route.

Comment: Search for the local action manager class, there you can look for the possible parameters that you can provide in the YAML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basing on [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2007444#comment-11033787) found on [Local action links now provided by plugins using YAML discovery and implementing LocalActionInterface](https://www.drupal.org/node/2007444), this is the action declaration you should use.

```
amidori_utils.add_content:
  route_name: 'node.add'
  title: 'Add content'
  route_parameters:
    node_type: 'blog'
  appears_on:
      - view.admin_blogs.page_1
```

I take that, in your case, *node_type* should be simply *blog*, if that is the machine name for the content type you want to let users create.

Comment: Just want to document out loud: I had a bit of a time trying to find how to add a link to a Media (in core) bundle "Playlist" created in-house. The following worked:

    route_name: 'entity.media.add_form'
    title: 'Add Playlist'
    route_parameters:
      media_type: 'playlist'
    appears_on:
      - ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 route_name: node.add
 route_parameters:
   node_type: 'blog'
```

This will show node/add/blog.

Comment: Please add some more details to explain "***this***", that will prevent your answer will be perceived as low quality answer, which puts it at risk of being deleted via moderation ...

Comment: thanks for the pointer, @Nguyen Quoc. Your tip does help in solving the answer. However, i have to accept kiamlaluno's answer since it will help more people in the future.